# Retrieving title of most recent post in an RSS feed as quickly as possible

Tags: python, xml, rss

I am writing a Python script that depends on being able to poll an RSS feed for updates as quickly as possible. The relevant information for my purposes is contained in the title of the post. I would like to spend no more time than necessary retrieving it. I have tried loading the entire feed but that is too slow for my liking. Is it possible to, for example, only retrieve a certain number of bytes instead of the entire feed? I know that there are ways to abort the loading of a webpage when a certain condition is triggered, but I am not sure how to do something like this for an RSS feed.